# Amazon AWS For Whois?

Tags: php, python, amazon-web-services, whois

I was looking for a Whois Api, but most of them charge heavy price and not reliable enough. We can code in Python or Php.

We need to make a Whois lookup service, to integrate with our site. What AWS Resource we need for this? We need at least 5k lookups per day.

AWS provides: S3 , elastic, and others. We are confused. As Amazon provides free tire. Does it allow who is lookup? As google app engine never allowed this.

Comment: Can't you just query whois.ripe.net? Or am I on the wrong page here?

Comment: This [Whois API](http://whois-api.domaininformation.de/) comes with 11000 free requests per month.

Answer (score 0):

The Amazon service you want to use is the server service: EC2.
You get full access to a server and, of course, you can performs socket connections on port 43 (the one required by the Whois protocol).